# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am upgrading spring boot 2.5.12 to Spring boot 2.7.2 in gradle kotlin. As per the link given <https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter > . When I have removed deprecated websecurityconfigureradapter getting exception. Code snippet is given below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class BasicAuthC {
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/anything"")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests(requests -> requests.anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated())
                .httpBasic()
         return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager memoryUserDetailsManager() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

        return  new InMemoryUserDetailsManager (User.withUsername("testUserName").password(encoder.encode("****")).
                authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SOME_ROLE")).build());

    }
}   


import com.azure.spring.aad.webapi.AADJwtBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Order(2)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class OAuthTwoConfiguration  {

    @Profile(value="OAUTHPROFILE")
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/test").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new AADJwtBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Profile(value = "test")
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer WebSecurityCustomizer () throws Exception {

        return (web)->web.ignoring().antMatchers("/someAPI");
    }
}
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:106) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
... 22 common frames omitted

Answer (score 4):

Either your code or some of the libraries that you use are still providing `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Check your code again, maybe you are forgetting some place.

Try to update the libraries that you use to the latest versions.

If they are not migrated yet, you'll might have to wait until they are, before you get rid of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Comment: I have checked that also , It is coming from class AADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter which is in azure-spring-boot-3.1.0 . How we can integrate spring security filter chain with Spring cloud

Comment: Is there a new version of it?

Comment: yes . I have checked this with spring cloud 4.3.0 . but getting the same exception